# library not found for -lsqlite3.0

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

When I run the app in ios device to make ipa file, this error appear. How I can solve this problem?? PLZ help me.

ld: library not found for -lsqlite3.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project settings (and the left-hand pane, selected using Command-1) remove the reference to sqlite3.0 and replace them with sqlite3 instead (i.e changing "3.0" to just "3").