# library not found for -lsqlite3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sqlite

Hello friends I'm new in iOS. I'm creating an app using sqlite. the app is running perfectly in simulator but not working in iPhone device. I search a lot but not getting the right solution. I got a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002523/library-not-found-for-lsqlite3-0)  but it also not worked for me.

[image]

I downloaded some demo app of sqlite, but all apps showing same error. I'm not understanding what happened.
PLZ help me I stuck with this issue.

Comment: can you show the screen shot

Comment: plz check, i have send screen shot

Answer (score 2):

see the `libsqlite3.o.tbd` is shows on red color , just delete and add again and finally clean and run once .the visibility shows as black not red, see the attached image

[image]

**updated answer**

[image]

finally do clean and run

Comment: Thanks karthik for you reply but tried this also and i also added "libsqlite3.dylib". I don't know what is the difference between .tbd and .dylib but i tried it also. In my xcode only libsqlite3.tbd is showing.I tried link that is given in my question. after that if only showing libsqlite3.tbd

Comment: .dylib - in xcode6 and below we used, the updated xcode (7 and above)  we used .tbd extension

Comment: Thanks karthik for this information but i am still stuck in this issue. Can you tell where i can find libsqlite3.tbd in system. I have doubt that it only showing in xcode but may be  by mistaken i deleted the file.I am confused.

Comment: @karthik i did , but same result. I am not understanding what is going on.

Comment: @Udaikumar - one more doubt in your projcet are you used the coocapods

Comment: @Udaikumar - see this once http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/04/09/library-not-found-tip-for-iphone-developers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118382/discussion-between-udai-kumar-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 1):

Open xCode click top project blue icon. Click Target-> build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> add Other -> open Folder -> click Windows+Shift+G ->Enter /usr/lib then select library and add to your Project

try it.

Comment: I did this also , I got only dylib file not tbd file. I aslo added and worked but its not work same error.

Comment: dylib is also available in this Folder udai kumar

Comment: yes that i want to say i got only libsqlite3.dylib not libsqlite3.tbd Avinash, I used libsqlite3.dylib this and build project but same error i found Avinash. I tried your answer but nothing is happening. Plz help

Comment: add libz.dylib and try it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is my Xcode. I deleted my sqlite library by mistake that's it is not showing my sqlite library path. I uninstalled and installed new Xcode, and my issue resolved.